# Listview onTouch within a ListFragment single click not working

Tags: java, android, android-listfragment, ontouchlistener

I a using a Fragment which extends a ListFragment, this then uses an ArrayAdapter in order to create a dynamic list of custom rows (this is all working perfectly).

What I am now trying to do is implement an onTouch event where when the user swipes each row left of right then do something. This logic is all working the only issue is I am having to do the onTouch event as the ACTION_UP does not seem to get called first time.

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, final int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    v.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        int initialX = 0;
        final float slop = ViewConfiguration.get(getActivity()).getScaledTouchSlop() * 1.5f;

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(final View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch(event.getActionMasked()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    initialX = (int) event.getX();

                    return true;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    // Do something here

                    return false;
            }

            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

I am returning true from the ACTION_DOWN so from my understanding this should indicate to the onTouch event to continue processing touch events and in my above code this will be the ACTION_UP when the user lifts his finger from the screen, not sure what I am missing here.

Further to this if at all possible I would also like to bind an onClick event onto the same view (not essential as already have workaround if I can get above working).

Answer (score 0):

You must have used **OnTouchListener** listener for swiping each rows of listView, make sure that you are returning false on ACTION_UP event.

Parent view receives a call back only when child views have not consumed it. So if each rows of list view is having a **onTouchListener**, you have to propagate event to parent by returning false.

Hope it will help.

Comment: I am already using a onTouchListener on the parent of the listview, I just need the entire row to be clickable. Therefore, as you can see I have setOnTouchListener on the view itself and not the listview.

Comment: Then how are you swiping each row left or right. If you are not using onTouchListener for each row.

Comment: I am using it on the View (row). My listview contains multiple views, each view represents a row. I then attach the listener on the view (row).

Comment: Yes that what i m talking about return false on enent_down and event_up but true on event move for each row. What is happening here is event does not populate to parent if you consume event_down and up on row listener

Comment: Tried that and it did not walk just debugged it a little more, based on my above code what happens is the action_down code works, what happens on first click nothing is picked up, then on second click its works as it should.

Comment: Just worked out the issue, as I am adding the listener onItemClick, the first click essentially sets the listener then the second works as it should. So what I need to set the listener within the custom ArrayAdaper, however am not sure how I can call my private functions that are within my Fragment from the custom ArrayAdapter?

Comment: Create an interface containing a method, implement in fragment and pass to arrayAdapter and call your interface method wherever you want to call private method.

Comment: Thanks for your help, your comments helped me work out a fix, passed in the fragment into my ArrayAdapter so that I can directly access all methods within my fragment and all is now working.